# Self-adjoint operator as composition of bounded and self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

My teacher gave me a problem:
I have two self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$. Both of them are greater or equal than $I$, i.e. $A \geq I$ and $B \geq I$. I need to to prove that there is a positive bounded operator $T$ for which $B=TAT$.
But I don't understand what means greater or equal for operators and i don't have any idea how to solve this problem. Would be glad for any help.

Comment: Greater than or equal for self-adjoint operators means that their difference is positive semidefinite i.e. $A \geq B \iff A-B \geq 0$. Equivalently $A\geq B$ if for every vector $\psi$ we have $\langle \psi | A \psi\rangle \geq\langle \psi | B \psi\rangle$, where the angle brackets indicate the inner product.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me